# Independence in gene set enrichment testing

Tags: independence, biostatistics, bioinformatics

Edit: I apologize if the question is considered to broad. In fact, it is concerning a very specific task in bioinformatic analysis of high throughput data set, and in my opinion the problem presented here, albeit not formulated formally, is very specific.

In HT data sets in biology, such as transcriptome profiles, very frequently we have a large number of variables (e.g. genes) which are somehow measured. The results of an experiment provide us with lists of significantly regulated genes which often include thousands of variables that, after correction for multiple testing, still show a significant difference. To interpret such results biologists often use a technique called "gene set enrichment analysis". Variables such as genes can be grouped a priori into sets which share a common biological mechanism (for example, genes stimulated by interferon). We now ask the question, which sets of genes are significantly enriched among the genes that are differentially expressed. The simplest (but not optimal) way to test it statistically is to use a contingency table (gene in set / gene not in set vs gene significantly regulated / gene not significantly regulated) and a suitable test such as hypergeometric test.

However, there is not a single gene set that we test, but a number of them. And, worse, these sets include often the same genes; for example, different diseases may result in the same genes being up-regulated, so gene sets defined for these diseases will overlap.

A core practical problem in testing for significant gene set enrichment¹ is that many gene sets overlap to a large extent. For example, the gene sets A and B which are characteristically enriched in diseases A and B may both include interferon inducible genes -- therefore, both sets will be enriched in any condition that involves interferon induction.

This of course has statistical problems -- if the tests on different gene sets are not independent, how can we use an FDR or FWER correction that assumes independence? And yet, this is what is usually done.

This poses also a practical problem for the person interpreting the results: I get 100 significant gene sets, however only one handful of genes driving that response in all of the genes.

One way of solving this problem has been implemented in the hyperGTest by Falcon and Gentleman ([R package GOstats](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/GOstats/inst/doc/GOstatsHyperG.pdf)). Here, the gene set analysis is performed several times. Given the hierarchical structure of gene sets defined by GO terms, for each given node, the test is performed only using the genes that were not present in any significantly enriched children of a given node:

> When ’conditional(p) == TRUE’, the ’hyperGTest’ function uses the
>   structure of the GO graph to estimate for each term whether or not
>   there is evidence beyond that which is provided by the term’s children
>   to call the term in question statistically overrepresented. The
>   algorithm conditions on all child terms that are themselves
>   significant at the specified p-value cutoff. Given a subgraph of one
>   of the three GO ontologies, the terms with no child categories are
>   tested first. Next the nodes whose children have already been tested
>   are tested. If any of a given node’s children tested significant, the
>   appropriate conditioning is performed.

This heuristics gives, from the point of view of a biologist, results which are much more easily interpreted -- boring repetitions are avoided; if B is significant, then A is reported only if there is additional information in A not already contained in B.

My questions:

1. What is the validity of the above procedure from a purely statistical point of view?
2. Given no hierarchical structure, how could one implement such a heuristics?

Not being a bayesian statistician myself, given that what I am interested in is a measure of novel information provided by a set of genes, I imagine a bayesian approach could be a way to go.

Any hints are welcome!

¹ there exists a range of statistical tests used, including U-test, hypergeometric testing, ANOVA variants, randomization tests and many more. The issue I am describing here remains for most if not all of them.

Comment: can you please add a tag wiki for your new tag `gsea`?  WHAT DOES IT MEAN?

Comment: I will remove the tag. Should I delete the question? Apparently it is not considered specific enough.

Comment: +1. This is a very interesting question. If you don't get an answer, you might want to post it on a bioinformatics website such as biostars, seqanswers or Bioconductor support forum.

Comment: @Will Do we really need the [gsea] tag, given that we have [bioinformatics]? I am not sure. I noticed that you started retagging other questions, it's usually a good idea to discuss such things on Meta first (see [tag-proposal] tag on Meta).

Comment: @amoeba good question, especially as it is not a technique as such (but then again, what is "bioinformatics"? I don't know, and my job description says that I'm a bioinformatician). It should have been discussed on Meta, I agree. However, given that there are ~ half a milion hits in google.scholar for "gene set enrichment" (and 25K for the exact phrase), I didn't give it much thought. Sorry!

Comment: @Will Given the above discussion which clearly indicates doubt about the value of the tag, please stop adding the tag to posts. Given that doubt, the best thing to do is post on meta explaining why you think the tag should be used and asking if that's reasonable; if there's something like a consensus for it, then fine, go ahead and add it (given the usual caveats about bumping posts). If there's much opposition, you'll need to remove it (or someone else will).

Comment: In general, we allow non-statistical tags that refer to the field of study (such as e.g. [bioinformatics] or [neuroscience]), but it does not make sense to be too specific here. [Bioinformatics] has only 134 threads, that's definitely NOT too many. So I would say there is no reason to create sub-tags. By the way, [enrichment] tag appears useless too, and should probably be eliminated.

Comment: I suggest to take this discussion elsewhere, as it does not really concern my particular post. Speaking of which, do you think (@amoeba, @Glen_b) that my question is not relevant in stats? If yes, I will be happy to remove it.

Comment: The question is definitely on-topic and raises an interesting issue (+1). I don't see it as too broad at all, because it asks *very specifically* about this hyperGTest procedure. In fact, I would rather be worried that it's too specific and is unlikely to be answered because I guess few (if any) people here are familiar with hyperGTest. [As a small comment to your question, FDR or FWER corrections usually do not assume independence, contrary to what you wrote.]

Comment: No problem, @Will. The tag was created by January when he or she posted this Q. I suggest we replace it with [bioinformatics] everywhere, and probably do the same with the [enrichment] tag. Do you agree it makes sense? If so, would you want to do it?

Comment: @amoeba: regarding requirement of independence; I understand that certain procedures (like BH) work for some types of dependence. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand that BH works when there is a positive dependence / the PRDS property (for true nulls). However, firstly, I don't know whether this is the case here (a formal comment would be greatly appreciated), secondly, I don't know whether anyone seriously considered this. We (biologists / bioinformaticians) simply acquired a Pavlov instinct to apply BH whenever we see more than 5 p-values in a column. I'm exaggerating, but not much.

Comment: The hierarchy of GO is also covered in [topGO](https://bioconductor.org/packages/topGO) package, which handles genes in several GO terms differently (If selected the right function) topGO starts from the bottom of more specific terms and builds toward the more general term bringing some score from the child process.