# Does ordering the comparisons by p-value make sense?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, effect-size, ranking, bioinformatics

In bioinformatics I usually do enrichment test (read hypergeometric test) with many comparisons over the same list. After correcting for multiple comparisons I usually order the results by p-value (lowest at the top). In order to focus on those that are significant in more strict threshold.

However I got a comment stating that I shouldn't do this:

> You shouldn't be ranking by p-value. The p-value is only an indication of whether the observed change is statistically significant, not an indication of the magnitude of the observed change.

What are the downsides of ordering by p-value?

If I have magnitude size and the p-value I usually rank first by the magnitude and then by p-value, but in the absence of a magnitude, is this reasonable?

I could probably switch to fisher to calculate the odds ratio, but most implementations I see use the hypergeometric test.

---

Example:

Say I do a differential expression analysis and I select 2000 genes as truly differentially expressed. Next I want to know what are they involved in. So I test (hypergeometric test) if from these 2000 genes out of the 20000 (universe) genes measured in the expression analysis are involved in a pathway related to cell growth or not (size 200) and other pathways that might have other size (400 or 20 or ...).

Comment: I assume you have the same sample size for all your comparisons, is that true? (This would be the case if e.g. you run the test for a large number of genes, across the same samples). If so, then p-value is a monotonic function of effect size, so ordering by p-value and ordering by effect size is exactly equivalent.

Comment: Yes, the universe is the same (20000 genes) but each test is done with a subset of different size (20, 200, 400, or 2200).

Comment: What is "universe"? I don't understand. E.g. in differential expression analysis you would have n_1 samples in group A and n_2 samples in group B and for each gene you would compare its expressions between A and B. Sample size (n_1 and n_2) stays the same for each gene. Does this resemble your case?

Comment: I didn't mention differential expression and I am not doing differential expression. But say I do a differential expression analysis and I select 2000 genes as truly differentially expressed. Next I want to know what are they involved in. So I test (hypergeometric test) if from these 2000 genes out of the 20000 (universe) genes measured in the expression analysis are involved in a pathway related to cell growth or not (size 200). But another pathway might be (400 or 20). (And a gene can be in several pathways, but that's a different problem?)

Comment: @amoeba Thanks to you! Perhaps [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/270092/105234) will help to know the background.